# To determine asymptotic distribution, when to ignore lower-order $O_p$ terms?

Tags: asymptotics

Let $A_{m,n} + B_{m,n}$ be such that:

1. $A_{m,n} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} A$ as $m,n \rightarrow \infty$
2. $A_{m,n} = O_p(\sqrt{nm(n+m)})$
3. $B_{m,n} = O_p(\sqrt{mn})$.

Under what conditions would the asymptotic distribution of $A_{m,n} + B_{m,n} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} A$ as $m,n \rightarrow \infty$? i.e., when can you ignore the lower-order term $B_{m,n}$? Is that even possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To have

$$A_{m,n} + B_{m,n} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} A$$

it must be the case that $B_{m,n} \overset{p}{\rightarrow}0$, or equivalently, that $B_{m,n} =o_p(1)$, i.e. that $B_{m,n}$ goes "on its own" to zero, in probability.

What you have is that $B_{m,n} = O_p(\sqrt{mn})$. But this means that $B_{m,n}$ needs to be divided by $\sqrt{mn}$ in order to remain bounded in probability). Which implies that, on its own, it diverges. So $A_{m,n} + B_{m,n}$ does not converge in distribution.